# PreviousPage in .ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ashx

Is it possible to retrieve the equivalent of `Page.PreviousPage` within a generic .ashx handler, following a cross-page PostBack from an .aspx page?

I need to access some POST values from the Page performing the PostBack and - while I could simply use `Request.Form` - the values in question come from WebControls and, as such, have rather obscure (and not very robust) names (e.g. ctl00$WebFormsContent$SomeControl$SomeOtherControl$txtWhatever).

I have tried the following:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Page previous = context.PreviousHandler as Page;
    if (previous != null)
        context.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

However, this does not work - upon debugging, I can see that `context.PreviousPage` is null.

Is there a way to retrieve this information and cast it as a `Page`?

Comment: Maybe try the referer property?

Comment: @EladLachmi I could get the URL of the previous page in this manner; however, this wouldn't be equivalent to `Page.PreviousPage` in that there would be no maintained viewstate.

Comment: I don't think viewstate will be maintained even if you could get the page object. If you need data from that page, how about doing a post?

Comment: @EladLachmi Sorry, when I wrote "viewstate", what I actually meant to write was "controls collection." Please see my updated question.

Comment: Same thing basically... You need the values inside the controls and those are kept in viewstate. They will not be available, even if you do manage to get a reference with the page object AFAIK.

Comment: @EladLachmi This is typically possible when using either cross-page postbacks or `Server.Transfer` - the references exist in the `__PREVIOUSPAGE` POST value - I just want to emulate the construction of the `Page` object as `PreviousPage` does not exist in a generic handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PreviousHandler` will not help you here. To get your HttpHandler to receive a cross-page PostBack, you have to understand the underlying workings of this.

Refer: [Redirecting Users to Another Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x3x8t37x.aspx)

> Cross-page posting is similar to hyperlinks in that the transfer is
>   initiated by a user action. However, in cross-page posting, the target
>   page is invoked using an HTTP POST command, which sends the values of
>   controls on the source page to the target page. In addition, if the
>   source and target page are in the same Web application, the target
>   page can access public properties of the source page. As always, all
>   of the pages in the application can share information stored in
>   session state or application state.

As will be clear after reading that bit, all the values you are looking for are actually sent to your handler as POST variables.

You can find them in the `context.Request.Params` collection.

Now that you have the request from your page, lets say Page1.aspx in your handler; we need to create an object that can handle and processing this request. This is an instance of your Page1 object.

```
string pagePath = "~/Page1.aspx";                   //virtual path to your page
Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(pagePath); //find the type

//create an object of your page
Page myPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
myPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);         //process the request
```

After you have processed the current request using your object, you will find the Controls collection is populated and filled with the input data. You can now use exposed properties or `FindControl` to find the necessary controls and fetch input from them.

Comment: Hi nunespascal - indeed, I can access the values I want through `Request.Form`; however, the values are all posted from WebControls and as such have the typically obscure POST variable names (ctl00$WebFormsContent$...), which I would rather avoid hard-coding.

Comment: Added the steps to dynamically create a Page object to process the post data. You should be able to fetch any data from it now just as you would have using `PreviousPage`